# MySQL namespace in create table

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I give the namespace on the table create syntax ? Like below in com.sumeet.QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS

It is not working with below syntax

```
CREATE TABLE "com"."sumeet"."QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS"(
SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
JOB_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
JOB_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(250) NULL,
JOB_CLASS_NAME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
IS_DURABLE VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
IS_NONCONCURRENT VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
IS_UPDATE_DATA VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
REQUESTS_RECOVERY VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
JOB_DATA BLOB NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP));
```

Comment: Name of the database is your "namespace". What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: Use `"com.sumeet"."QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS"`

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have a table: qrtz._job_details, and a database: sumeet, so what's com?

Comment: I wanted to add namespace before the name of the table @Strawberry

Comment: If you get any error message, you should post it in your question. Then we would at least see, that you are really using MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of a hierarchy in MySQL. ie. No folders, containers or namespaces for your databases.

MySQL has 2 concepts: A database (Often referred to as a Schema), and tables. You'd need to name your database `"com.sumeet"` (Which is allowed, but can be considered messy*), and your table: `QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS`. Various software (like PHPMyAdmin) will look at the similarities and will group databases together into folders based on the name itself. For example, if you use underscores `"com_sumeet"` phpmyadmin will actually group those together:

[image]

**Note:** Naming your database with periods is likely more trouble than it's worth, due to the fact that your database calls will now require quotes in order to function correctly. (ie. `"com.test".table` vs `com_test.table`) Period is the universal separator between databases and tables, so the quotes are required to tell MySQL specifically what is a database, and what is the table in your queries.

Comment: It's allowed, but it strikes me as a bad idea.

Comment: @Strawberry How's my update?

Comment: Amazing. Awesome. Superb.